# gwt compoenents does not render

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

all of a sudden gwt components have stopped rendering after our yesterdays' deployment to google app engine for java.

we have tried many times. and on looking into firebug i see

Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'
http://1-ps.googleusercontent.com/x/s.sakshumweb-hrd.appspot.com/www.sakshum.org/sakshumwebgae/B365B696BAAE7DD00F53BC81F86AF51C.cache.html
Line 2860

i am not sure why this is happening. can some one please advise

The allowed static file is

```
<static-files>
        <include path="/**.xml" expiration="30d 1h" />
        <include path="/**.txt" expiration="30d 1h" />
        <include path="/**.html" expiration="30d 1h" />
        <include path="/favicon.ico" expiration="30d 1h"/>
        <include path="/**.ico" expiration="30d 1h" />
    <include path="/**.js" expiration="30d 1h" />
    <include path="/**.css" expiration="30d 1h" />
    <include path="/**.gif" expiration="30d 1h" />
    <include path="/**.JPG" expiration="30d 1h" />
    <include path="/**.jpg" expiration="30d 1h" />
    <include path="/**.jpeg" expiration="30d 1h" />
    <include path="/**.png" expiration="30d 1h" />
     <include path="/**.htc" expiration="30d 1h" />
     <include path="*.nocache." expiration="0s" />
     <include path="*.cache." expiration="365d" />
     <exclude path="**.gwt.rpc" />
</static-files>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.cache.js` is loaded cross-origin (from `www.sakshum.org` to `1-ps.googleusercontent.com`. That *ps* in the URL probably stands for Page Speed, which rewrites links to static assets.

I don't know how it works on GAE/J but either disbale Page Speed (if possible), or recompile your app using the `xsiframe` linker (in your `gwt.xml`):

`<add-linker name="xsiframe" />`

Comment: i do not see gwt.xml at all in my application. where it should be?

Comment: ok i think by adding to gwt.xml u meant <module>.gwt.xml i did that and now on tyring to compile i get

Loading inherited module 'vik.sakshum.sakshumweb.AdminModule'
   [ERROR] Invalid linker name 'xsiframe'
   [ERROR] Line 4: Unexpected exception while processing element 'add-linker'

Comment: Which version of GWT are you using?! Maybe try `<add-linker name="xs" />`

Comment: Make sure you put that line **after** the `<inherits/>` lines. The linkers are all defined in `com.google.gwt.core.Core` which must therefore be inherited _before_ you can `<add-linker/>`